# Continuity and convergence in $C[-2, 2]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the linear functional $\delta(x) = x(0)$ with $x \in C[-2, 2]$ and a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $C[-2, 2]$ that satisfies the following properties:

1. $f_n(t) = 0$ for $|t| > 1/n$.
2. $f_n(t) \geq 0$ for $|t| \leq 1/n$.
3. $\int_{-2}^2 f_n(t) dt = 1$.

Define functionals
$$
\varphi_n(x) = \int_{-2}^2 f_n(t) x(t) dt, x \in C[-2, 2].
$$

Prove that functionals $\varphi_n$ are continuous with norm topology in $C[-2, 2]$ and
that $\varphi_n$ converges to $\delta$ in the weak-$*$ topology.

I have no idea what to do in here. I was looking for similar ideas and the closer example I found was related to integral operators using Arzela-Ascoli theorem for proving that an operator is compact, but it seems far away from what they are asking for. Is there any standard way to tackle and solve this kind of problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\varphi_n \in C^0([-2,2])^*$ (the algebraic dual space) you need to show that $\varphi_n \in C^0([-2,2])'$ the topological dual space given by continuous forms. To do so, you need to show that it is continuous. Since it is linear, you need to show that there is a real number $M$ such that
$$\forall g \in C^0([-2,2]), \, |\varphi_n (g) | = |\langle \varphi_n,g\rangle| \leqslant M \|g\|_\infty$$
I let you show that $M = 1$ works.

Once you have that, you need to show that $\varphi_n$ weakly-* converges to $\delta$ the Dirac in $0$.

A quick reminder: for $f_n \in C^0([-2,2])$, $g_n$ weakly converges to $g$ iff $\forall \psi \in C^0([-2,2])', \, \langle \psi , g_n\rangle = \psi(g_n) \to \psi(g) = \langle \psi , g\rangle$.
Then you have a canonical injective and continuous morphism:
$$\begin{array}{rrcl}
J:&C^0([-2,2]) & \longrightarrow & C^0([-2,2])''\\
& g & \longmapsto & (\psi \mapsto \langle \psi,g \rangle)
\end{array}$$

Note here that $C^0([-2,2])''$ is a way bigger vector space than $C^0([-2,2])$. Hence $J(C^0([-2,2]))$ is a small part of $C^0([-2,2])''$
With this you can define the weakly-* convergence:
$\psi_n \in C^0([-2,2])'$ weakly-* converges if
$$\forall \Phi \in J(C^0([-2,2])''), \, \Phi(\psi_n) \to \Phi(\psi)$$
which is equivalent to
$$\forall g \in C^0([-2,2]), \, \langle \psi_n, g \rangle \to \langle \psi, g \rangle$$

Which means you only need to prove that for each $g \in C^0([-2,2])$,
$$\langle \varphi_n, g \rangle = \int_{-2}^2 f_n g \to \langle \delta,g\rangle = g(0)$$

And it does since each $g$ is continuous

Comment: Indeed, $\lvert \int_{-2}^2 f_n(t) x(t) dt \rvert \leq \int_{-2}^2 f(t) |x(t)| dt \leq \int_{-2}^2 f_n(t) \lVert x \rVert_{\infty} dt = \lVert x \rVert_{\infty}$. Thanks for your detailed explanation, it gave me a lot of intuition about the steps to analyze the problem.

Comment: You’re more than welcome, I’m happy you managed to solve it :)

Answer (score 1):

The limit functional $\varphi=\delta_0$ is given by $\varphi(g)=g(0).$ Hence we need to show that for any $g\in C[-2,2]$ there holds $\varphi_n(g)\to \varphi(g).$ We have $$\varphi_n(g)- \varphi(g)=\int\limits_{-1/n}^{1/n}f_n(t)g(t)\,dt-g(0)\\ =\int\limits_{-1/n}^{1/n}f_n(t)[g(t)-g(0)]\,dt$$ Hence $$|\varphi_n(g)- \varphi(g)|\le \int\limits_{-1/n}^{1/n}f_n(t)|g(t)-g(0)|\,dt\\ \le \max_{|t|\le {1\over n}}|g(t)-g(0)|\ \int\limits_{-1/n}^{1/n}f_n(t)\,dt\\ =\max_{|t|\le {1\over n}}|g(t)-g(0)|$$ The last quantity tends to $0$ due to the continuity of $g$ at $0.$

**Remark** The  proof indicates that the nonnegativity of $f_n$ can be dropped and replaced by the assumption $\sup_n\|f_n\|_1<\infty.$ That assumption is necessary in view of the Banach-Steinhaus theorem.

Comment: A sequence in the topological dual space converges to a functional if and only if it converges to the same functional with the weak-$*$ topology seems to be what I should have thought to direct the solution. Thanks!